# Why does HTML encoding prevent certain XSS attacks?

Tags: html, xss

I have been reading that you HTML encode on the way back from the server to the client (I think?) and this will prevent many types of XSS attacks. However, I don't understand at all. The HTML is still going to be consumed and rendered by the browser right?

How is this stopping anything?

I've read about this in multiple locations, websites and books, and nowhere does it actually explain *why* this works.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this question. It seems reasonable enough to me. Additionally it's important to have a good understanding of how web vulnerabilities work so they can be avoided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think about it: What does **encoded** HTML look like? For example, it could look like this:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;www.stackoverflow.com&quot;&gt;
```

So it will be rendered on the client as the literals (as <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">), not as HTML. Meaning you won't see an actual link, but the code itself.

XSS attacks work on the basis that someone can make a client browser parse HTML that the  site provider didn't intend to be on there; if the above weren't encoded, it would mean that the provided link would be embedded in the site, although the site provider didn't want that.

XSS is of course a little more elaborate than that, and usually involves JavaScript as well (hence the Cross Site **Scripting**), but for demonstration purposes this simple example should suffice; it's the same with JavaScript code as with simple HTML tags, since XSS is a special case of the more general HTML injection.

Comment: OH! This makes sense now. So the browser *won't* render it as HTML. I was in the context of ASP.NET MVC and how it uses HTML encoding, and was thinking it was using it for actual HTML that it intended to display. Now I understand it was only using it in reference to values.

Answer (score 1):

HTML encoding turns `<div>` into `&lt;div&gt;`, which means that any HTML markup will display on the page as text, rather than executed as HTML markup.

The basic entities that are converted are:

- `&` to `&amp;`
- `<` to `&lt;`
- `>` to `&gt;`
- `"` to `&quot;`

[OWASP recommends encoding some additional characters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content):

- `'` to `&#x27;`
- `/` to `&#x2F;`

These encodings are how you textually represent characters that would otherwise be consumed as markup. If you wanted to write `a<b` you'd have to be careful that `<b` isn't treated like an HTML element. If you use `a&lt;b` the text that will be displayed to the user will be `a<b`.