# WCF/Serverside - Validate string for Javascript/HTML elements

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wcf, xss

I'm currently going through our WCF REST services, and in some instances there is the possibility of a user inserting Javascript/HTML directly into our database. This is unacceptable, as we don't want XSS attacks occurring to our internal and external clients. Our services are not yet live, so no risk yet.

I've read up on several ways to implement ways of preventing XSS for web applications, but I've not found any conclusive solution for WCF REST services.

I was wondering if a library exists that can be used in WCF to validate strings from incoming data before saving it to the database. Similar to the way ASP.NET uses it's ValidateRequest method on each page submission.

Does a library or method like this exist that can be used in WCF?

Thanks

Comment: HTML Encoding the input string should prevent XSS attacks. Similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475306/why-does-html-encoding-prevent-certain-xss-attacks

Comment: EDIT. NVM, that similar question answered everything I need to know! Thanks. You can put that as the answer and I'll mark it :)

Comment: Some good explanation provided already there on the question. A must read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking it in WCF, I will suggest you to check it at web application level itself (means at the client side only). You must be having some text box that will be accepting data from end-user and then you would be passing that data to WCF. So via javascript you can validate at client side only (use RegEx).

```
A regex to accept all char except angular brackets is
"^[\s]*[a-z]+[\(|a-z\-\a-z|0-9|,|.| \)]*[a-z| ]*$"
```

Checking at client side will reduce the network trip and will increase the performance. But if in your use case you are not in position to validate at client side then you can do the same at the server side too. In that case you have to place that validation in WCF. If your string has angular brackets **<>** then in that case avoid inserting that value in DB.