# Encode and decode html to prevent xss in VB

Tags: vb.net, xss

I want to prevent xss in my application. I have an text input for which I should be able to accept for example `<script>alert(1)</script>` but as I save this, if I encode it using : `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.txtUsername.Text)`

I will be able to save the encoded version of this string:

```html
&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;
```

how should I show this later on without letting the script be executed?
if I decode it the script will be executed. 
I want to later on show this as `<script>alert(1)</script>`

Comment: please add a tag indicating which web technology you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does HTML encoding prevent certain XSS attacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475306/why-does-html-encoding-prevent-certain-xss-attacks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is not being decoded you may use jQuery

`$("<div/>").html(yourString).text();`

Answer (score 1):

Just show the text. Don't decode it. Let the browser do that for you.

<script>alert(1)</script>

See also this answer regarding other types of XSS vulnerabilities that html encoding doesn't protect you from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222/69527

Comment: Hi Dennis,  somehow it stays in html form and does not get decoded. I am using chrome.

Comment: Maybe you could include more info in your question about how you are displaying the text.

Comment: I am storing the string using HtmlEncode and then retrieve the encoded string and display it on another page but the string is not being decoded.

Comment: Right. I was hoping you would share details of *how* you're displaying it since you're having trouble with that part.